# Comparing CSS-attribute value with String in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, eclipse

I'm trying to test whether the value of a CSS-attribute matches a certain string. The comparison works fine in JSFiddle where I get the expected result but Eclipse is different and seems to evaluate the following statement as false:

```
if ($('.span1').css('font-family') == 'Arial') { alert("True");}
```

Where as in JSFiddle it's evaluated as true and I get the window popping up saying True. Any help as to why this is happening and how I can solve it would be appreciated.

Link to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s8d90911/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('.span1').css('font-family')` has the value `"Arial"`, i.e. within double quotes. So if you're putting them in `if` statement, you then have to match the exact value of `"Arial"` with the code's return type. Try this and it will work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('.span1').css('font-family') === '\"Arial\"') {
    alert("Works");
  }
});
```

```css
.span1 {
  font-family: 'Arial';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="span1">A</span>
```

And here's the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/39tt9Lh9/).

Note the use of `\`. It is important to escape the quotes.